# Docker - SQL Server Linux auto shutdown

Tags: docker, sql-server-linux

This is a first time I use docker, so I'm trying install sql-server-linux use docker in MacOS Mojave. 
I'm read tutorial from https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-a-mac/. But I meet a problem, my database server auto shutdown.

I'm tried with `sudo` code but nothing change.

I'm research and nothing talk about this issue.

[image: My sreen shot]

Comment: I need re-open this.

Answer (score 2):

I have written several webcrallers and always find it easier to build them from the ground up! [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/) is a very nice module but it's documentation is a little lacking and can be quite challenging to begin with! I recommend using [BeautifulSoup4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4), Python bult in Urllib2, and some socket module! Good luck!

Comment: Please re-open this. I have reached your question limit :)